# In Xcode, how to build an Objective-C lib for an app to run on iOS SIMULATOR?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

We get the error below when we try to build an app that uses our Obj-C lib.

What do we set in the lib project to prevent this error?

Ultimately, app must run on iPhone (ios 12 or higher), but we want it to first run on simulator.

```
Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked library 'libmobile_sys_hub_lib.a' was built for iOS.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Xcode active scheme list (left side of project title bar) and select IOS SIMULATOR

Answer (score 0):

That means you built the library for iOS.  You need to build it for the iOS Simulator.  Eg:

`xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator`

You will probably want to distribute separate copies of your library: one for the sim and one for device.

Comment: How do I set it to do that in the Xcode project GUI?  I could not find a project or target setting for IOS simulator.

Comment: You would want to select an iOS Simulator run destination.